# Perl one line liner + match IP address

Tags: linux, perl, shell, ksh

I am trying to build Perl one line liner
that match exactly IP address from file , and print the matched IP

if IP not matched then it will not print the IP address .

REMARK - on the left/right side of IP address [left]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[right]  - could be any character but IP itself must be matched exactly

The problem is that not mater what I put after echo, Perl will print any string anyway

Please advice what the problem with with my syntax?

Some examples

```
     # export IP=23.45.7.0
```

should matched the IP

```
      # echo 23.45.7.0 | perl  -pe 'next if /^*#/;/(\b|\D)$ENV{IP}(\b|\D)/'
        23.45.7.0
```

should not matched the IP

```
       # echo 123.45.7.0 | perl  -pe 'next if /^ *#/; /(\b|\D)$ENV{IP}(\b|\D)/'
         123.45.7.0
```

should matched the IP

```
     # echo IP23.45.7.0IP | perl -pe 'next if /^ *#/; /(\b|\D)$ENV{IP}(\b|\D)/'
       IP23.45.7.0IP
```

should not matched the IP

```
       # echo 23.45.7.00 | perl  -pe 'next if /^ *#/; /(\b|\D)$ENV{IP}(\b|\D)/'
         23.45.7.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching common patterns you can look to [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aCommon) in this case, specifically `Regexp::Common::net`.

According to your specifications:

```
echo 10.11.12.13|perl -MRegexp::Common=net -nE '$_=~/^$RE{net}{IPv4}{-keep}$/ and say $1'
```

10.11.12.13

...whereas this invalid address isn't matched:

```
echo 10.11.1200.13|perl -MRegexp::Common=net -nE '$_=~/^$RE{net}{IPv4}{-keep}$/ and say $1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need **strip** the superfluous parts away. Plus you should escape the dots in the `$IP` so that it doesn't match e.g. `23x45y7z0`. For example like this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $ip = quotemeta($ENV{IP});

while (<>) {
    next if (/^ *$/);
    # try to replace everything by just the IP,
    # print if the line matched
    s/^.*(${ip}).*$/$1/ && print;
}
```

An ugly "one-liner" (remove the new-lines to reduce both the actual line count and readability):

```
perl -e 'my $ip = quotemeta($ENV{IP});
    while (<>) {
        next if (/^ *$/);
        s/^.*(${ip}).*$/$1/ && print;
    }'
```

The `-p` seems to be causing trouble here, since it prints the parsed lines if they don't match (see `man perlrun` for explanation). You could prevent that for example like this:

```
perl -pe 'my $ip = quotemeta($ENV{IP});
    next if (/^ *$/);
    if (s/^.*(${ip}).*$/$1/) {
        print;
    } else { 
        $_ = ""; 
    }'
```

Comment: how to write your code in - Perl one line liner ( because I need to add the perl one liner in my ksh script )

Comment: the problem is - if IP=23.45.7.00 or IP=123.45.7.0 then its also print the IP , while its shouldn’t print it , see my examples in my quastion

Comment: @Eytan it works for me, are you sure you don't have a typo somehere?

Comment: here what I get from my linux machines : # echo "23.45.7.00" | perl -e 'my $ip = quotemeta($ENV{IP}); > while (<>) { > next if (/^ *$/); > s/^.*(${ip}).*$/$1/ && print; > }' 23.45.7.0 , its print the ip = 23.45.7.0

Comment: @Eytan the script is not interpreting the numbers - if you set `IP=23.45.7.0` in the script's environment, do not expect it to print `23.45.7.00` (two trailing zeros instead of one).

Comment: I not mean that - it will print 23.45.7.00 , what I mean is that if IP address not matched  exactly , then not need to print anything

Comment: @Eytan no, the script isn't printing any part of a line if the IP isn't contained therein.